# How to create a View that covers the current Activity Android

Tags: java, android

I need to create a `View` programmatically that displays some information I have. The `View` should popup from the Current `Activity`. Like this:

[image]

Is there any library or example? Because in Android I really have no idea on how to start

Comment: is this view only for your activity ?

Comment: you can use a dialog with a custom view

Comment: try following link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `Dialog` to achieve your View Requirement.
You can create an `AlertDialog` problematically and add view elemets in to it.

**EDIT**

Reference code :

```
public static void wrappedImageDialog(final Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Get Pro", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("No thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.go_pro_dialog_layout, null);
        dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: ok that is what I was thinking too, but since I'm supporting android api 9+ do you know if it is possible to customize the Dialog elements?

Comment: Yes as per my implementation you can customize on API level 9.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start an Activity like a popup, you need to create an Activity and set this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

in the manifest.